# How to remove empty string in JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Nuxt returns an error when it receives empty strings from JSON:

Example error:

```
input must be a string (received string: "")
```

An example of my loop in Nuxt:

```
<Grid class="sponsors">
  <Img v-for="prop in home" :src="prop.sponsors" :width="300" />
</Grid>
```

JSON content:

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"title": "Film",
"desc": "Film desc",
"sponsors": "sponsors/culture-fond_ftl1iu_nhpivj.png",
"films": "film 1"
},
{
"id": "2",
"title": "",
"desc": "",
"sponsors": "sponsors/muzey-tavrida-bw_wedmvw_qf4ixd.png",
"films": "film 2"
},
{
"id": "3",
"title": "",
"desc": "",
"sponsors": "sponsors/insightstudio-logo-white_rc0vme.png",
"films": "film 3"
},
{
"id": "4",
"title": "",
"desc": "",
"sponsors": "",
"films": "film 4"
},
{
"id": "5",
"title": "",
"desc": "",
"sponsors": "",
"films": "film 5"
},
{
"id": "",
"title": "",
"desc": "",
"sponsors": "",
"films": "film 6"
}
]
```

How do I remove empty string from JSON? Or how to ignore this error?

I use Nuxt 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to solve this problem.

You can use filter() in javascript (or something similar in other frameworks)

```
const filteredData = jsonData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val !== ""));
```

Another way to solve it would be to check for empty strings before rending the IMG component in Nuxt.

```
<Grid class="sponsors">
  <Img v-for="prop in home" :src="prop.sponsors" :width="300" v-if="prop.sponsors !== ''" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't understand how to apply this code: `const filteredData = jsonData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val !== ""));`


I get the json api like this: `const { data: home } = await useFetch(useRuntimeConfig().public.api + '/home')`

How to apply your code, can you show me an example? I would be very grateful to you!